# Freeze while installing Server 12.10 from USB

Tags: installation, 12.10, server, freeze

I'm putting together a new computer and trying to install Ubuntu Server 12.10 from USB (no optical drive). I'm using the AMD 64 bit installer (MD5 checksum reported fine) and [Pendrive](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/) to put it on my USB drive.

When I start the computer with the USB drive connected, I get to an initial language select screen and then to the boot screen (the one with the option to install, do a memory test, etc). When I select "Install Ubuntu Server" I'm taken to another language selection screen where I'm unable to do anything but hard shutdown the computer (no keyboard or mouse input accepted). How can I fix this freeze?

Additional info:

- USB appears to look like a UEFI drive in BIOS
- While a SSD is first in boot order, it's a blank drive (as are the HDDs)
- Using wireless USB keyboard the whole time. Keyboard works with other devices
- Legacy USB Support is enabled
- Using an AMD APU C-60

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After getting ahold of a PS2 keyboard, everything works. Looks like there's something up with using a USB keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Since this seems to be recurring problem, I will now additionally confirm, that:

- installing 13.04 server works on my server machine (from USB with USB keyboard)
- while installing 13.10 freezes at second language selection, where I had to hold POWER button for 4 secs to turn off my machine (total freeze)
- the same ISO, 13.10 server DOES NOT freeze under the same circumstances (logitech wireless keyboard and install from USB pendrive, EasyToBoot) ona DELL OPTIPLEX 755
- Desktop ISO 13.10 does not freeze, since it doesn't have this text mode portion of setup

So yanking the USB keyboard and plugging in a PS/2 one did the trick. Note, that DELL OPTIPLEX 755 does NOT have PS/2 ports.

Hope this helps anyone having the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I was experiencing the same thing in 13.10. I swapped the USB keyboard with a PS2 and it worked fine.